# How can i relate Fastify-Basic-Auth api with Frontend Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, typeorm, fastify, zod

i tried to implement login to my project, I'm using Fastify server, typeORM schema and zod validation, I implemented the API and  front side, but when i login,the routes in front side are accessible but they do not get data from API because erreur: unauthorization, I can't bind between the API and frontend authentication

note : i'm using basic auth strategy

```
export async function validate(username: string, password: string, request?: FastifyRequest, reply?: FastifyReply, done?: DoneFuncWithErrOrRes) {
    const user = await User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: username,
          }
    });
  
  if(user)
  {
    const isPassword = server.bcrypt.compare(user.password, password);
  if(isPassword) {
    done();
  } else {
    done(new Error("username or password incorrect!"));
  }}
}
```

index.ts file

```
server.register(fastifyBasicAuth, { validate });

server.after(() => {
// server.addHook("preHandler", basicAUTH);
server.get("/student/show-students", { preHandler: server.basicAuth },showStudent);
}
server.post("/login/login", userLogin);
```

frontend service

```
login(data: { email: string; password: string }){

    const credentials = btoa(`${data.email}:${data.password}`);
    const headers = { Authorization: `Basic ${credentials}` };
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.url}login`, {}, { headers });
   }
```